# Start spring boot from another application

Tags: java, spring-boot, processbuilder

I write launcher (for course project) for started application spring boot. I run spring boot app like this:

```
 Runnable runServer = () -> {
     try {
          ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java.exe", "-jar", "server/server.jar");
           pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
           process = pb.start();
           process.waitFor();
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }
        };
   Thread thread = new Thread(runServer);
   thread.start();
```

Application is runned, but no working:

Task manager:
[image]

Browser:

[image]

If I start application in cmd:

```
java -jar server.jar
```

Then everything works correctly, the application starts to open in the browser.
How start spring - boot application from another program? Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing specific to Spring that should cause your app to behave differently in these two situations.  The problem must have something to do with differences in the environments that are being set up for the app to run in.  Like @deadpool says, it might be that the port number is different in the two cases, and this would be because of the environment.  If you somehow have an environment variable set in your command line environment, your launcher might not be passing that variable through to the app's runtime environment.

Comment: ...another example is that I see that the CWD will be different in your two examples.  In the launcher case, you'll be in the directory above the **server** directory that contains your jar file.  In the second case, your CWD will be the **server** directory itself.  That may or may not change the behavior of the program.

Comment: There must be output from Spring besides what you're seeing in your browser.  I would suggest looking there for log or exception output that might tell you what is going wrong.

Comment: You should arrange for the process's standard output and standard error to be written somewhere that you can see it. The process may be producing an error message telling you why it's not working. Or it could be blocked writing a message to stdout or stderr because a buffer is full.

Comment: @Steve  i add output...and server is start succsesful. What?:) Post updated. Output correctly, does not containt error